# Ubuntu 12.04 minimal installation

Tags: 12.04

First of all I don't have much knowledge about linux stuff.

So, I am planning to buy a netbook this week and was thinking of installing `ubuntu 12.04` on it.

Is there any version of ubuntu 12.04 available to download which asks user to which package/applications the user wants to install or not so that I can get a minimal distribution for my system.

For, example

I was thinking of using `Xfce` or `LXDE` as my default desktop environment. So, the ubuntu CD let me choose whether or not I want to install Gnome/unity on my current system and at a latter stage when my installation is complete I can manually install `Xfce` or `LXDE`.

Also is this the correct way to install other desktop environments or one should first do a complete install of ubuntu and than remove and install a DE of his choice.So, if this is not the correct way than can you please point me to the correct way to achieve the other option I mentioned.

Please give UBUNTU specific anwers because I know I can get the above configuration using `Xubuntu` or `Lubuntu`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Please give UBUNTU specific anwers because I know I can get the above configuration using Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Firstly: Xubuntu *is* Ubuntu with xfce instead of unity. And lubuntu *is* Ubuntu with lxde instead of unity.

If you use the alternate CD (which has a much more detailed text-mode installer than the live CD), you get to choose exactly what gets installed, so you can install a minimal system and work from there. You can find it [on releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/).

You can also use the mini ISO. It uses the same installer, but is tiny, it downloads everything from the Internet: [i386](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) or [amd64](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)

Comment: Can you please provide the link for this alternate CD.

Comment: Edited my response

Comment: If I use mini ISO how will I configure my internet connection. Will it include network driver.

Comment: Yes, it will include network drivers

Comment: Thanks. I would have upvoted you but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: @ronnie: fixed that for you (upvote) ;)

Comment: @izx: That's nice :D