# Is there a fast or minimal installation option for Wubi?

Tags: windows, system-installation, wubi, startup-applications

I have recently installed Ubuntu on my Windows machine using the ~2.8 MB windows Installer. The installer then downloaded the necessary stuffs to complete the setup. This process took around 2 hours on a 5 mbps download speed.

On reviewing the initial installation, I have noticed that a lot of applications are installed, some of which I may or may not use.

My point is, is there a way to setup Ubuntu, so that the minimal amount of applications will be installed, and thus speed up the setup process by reducing the downloaded content.

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/144245/ubuntu-12-04-minimal-installation, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use server installation instead of desktop, then add packages after. That will significantly cut down initial download.

You add GUI (unity, gnome, lightdm, gdm, etc) later. They will function exactly the same as the desktop installation.

The major difference between Server and Desktop installation is all GUI and desktop related packages.

This [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=537870) provide a simple tweak to use wubi and install as a server, quote as below

> That said you can edit c:\wubi\install\preseed.cfg and set the package
>   to "ubuntu-standard".
>
> That will install a minimal set of packages, good enough to get a
>   useful shell and enable you to install other packages, from there you
>   can install any other ubuntu-server specifc package you want

Comment: Well if I eventually not use the system as server, won't it have unnecessary services running which would slow down the system?

Comment: OP used WUBI install. can the server version be installed via WUBI?

Comment: @ShamimHafiz The base installation is very very basic, you actually have to pick the service/server packages you want, even sshd. It has a suggested list of packages (one of them is sshd) at the end of the configuration process, you can just leave them un-check.

Comment: @user68186 Need a small tweak, I will update the answer.

Comment: If you run wubi.exe standalone, it downloads a ~500MB preinstalled disk image, so you have no control over which packages are installed. The only way to control it is if you run wubi with the ISO, which will then trigger an install to the virtual disks using `ubiquity` (and since the ISO is bigger than the diskimage, this doesn't actually save anything).

Comment: @bcbc: So as of now, there is no effective solution to the problem I discussed in the question?

Comment: @ShamimHafiz Not with Wubi. Use the mini ISO.

Comment: This no longer works, Ubuntu 14.04.